# A combinatorial sum involving ratios of binomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-identities

Can anyone suggest how to prove the following (for $k \le n$):

$$\sum \limits_{s=0}^N \frac{\binom{n}{k} \binom{N-n}{s-k} }{\binom{N}{s}} = \frac{N+1}{n+1}$$

I am assuming it to be true, and possibly well known.

Comment: Expand into factorials and recombine them into $\binom{s}{k}$ and $\binom{N-s}{n-k}$.

Comment: What's the context? How did you know what the answer should be?

Comment: Thank you Max! Simply, $\sum \limits_{s=0}^N \frac{\binom{n}{k} \binom{N-n}{s-k} }{\binom{N}{s}} =
\sum \limits_{s=0}^N \frac{\binom{s}{k} \binom{N-s}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}} =
\frac{N+1}{n+1}$ The last is evident from a basic counting argument

Comment: @David The context is the probability of observing a total of k 'items' after looking at n 'locations', in a world with a total of s items uniformly placed in N locations.

Comment: @JosephHeled I don't mean the problem itself, but broader context: a study in pure combinatorics, a lemma in a paper, or what?

Comment: @DavidRoberts the context is a very simple example which demonstrates Bayesian principles. This came up when computing the marginal.

Comment: @JosephHeled interesting! But, as it's closed, _and_ you've got your answer, I guess that's it :-)